Websocket stuck in CONNECTING readyState until ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED error
I have a simple python Flask backend using Asyncio:
# Simplified version of backend
connectedClients = {}

async def handler(webSocket):
    async for messageString in webSocket:
        print(f'Received message: { messageString }')

        message = json.loads(messageString)
        # Store the websocket connection
        connectedClients[message['data']['clientId']] = webSocket

        # Just echo back
        await webSocket.send(messageString)

async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(handler, '', 8001):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

and am using reconnecting-websocket  on my frontend to automatically handle websocket reconnection.  I'm using a socket middleware for Redux which creates the Socket, and passes in the appropriate url and message / onReconnected handlers.
import ReconnectingWebSocket from 'reconnecting-websocket';

export default class Socket {
  constructor(url, messageHandler, reconnectionHandler) {
    this.url = url;
    this.messageHandler = messageHandler;
    this.reconnectionHandler = reconnectionHandler;

    this.connect();
  }

  connect(callback = this.reconnectionHandler) {
    console.log("Connecting to ws");

    this.socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(this.url);
    this.socket.onmessage = message => this.messageHandler(message);
    this.socket.onopen = () => {
      console.log("Websocket onopen");
      callback();
    }
  }
}

When I force a network disconnect, the client will continue to attempt to reconnect and fail with ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED as expected, but once the network is restored, it will log "Connecting to ws" and then hang for a few seconds before erroring out with ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED.  Only after this ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED will the next reconnection attempt work (and it will reconnect in a matter of milliseconds).  If I look at the readystate of the websocket on the client during this time, it seems to be stuck in CONNECTING.
I'm trying to figure out how to make the reconnection not wait so long for the ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED error or otherwise to reconnect more quickly once the network connection has been restored.

Note: I was also having the same issue before switching to the reconnecting-websocket library, so I don't think it's related to that at all.
